# How do filtrations model information?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, finance, filtrations

Lets say you have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ And a stochastic process on this space $\{X_t, t \in T\}.$ Assume that our process takes values in $\mathbb{R}$ and $T$ is a totally ordered set.

You also have a filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t, t\in T\}$, where for each t, and each open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}$, $X_t^{-1}(U)\in \mathcal{F}_t$. We also have that for $s <t$, $\mathcal{F}_s\subset\mathcal{F}_t\subset\mathcal{F}$.

What I do not understand is how the filtration in some ways model information up to time $t$? Could you please explain this? In mathematical finance, it is said that the filtration models what information the investor has at time t? But I do not see the connection really; how does the filtration really tell us what kind of information we have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is meant by a filtration "contains the information" until time $t$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3131221/what-is-meant-by-a-filtration-contains-the-information-until-time-t)