# What does filtration contains (Stochastic calculus for finance)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, filtrations

I am reading the book Stochastic Calculus for Finance II. I have a problem about Filtration.
The author said that: 'A filtration tells us the information we will have at future times. More precisely, when we get to time t, we will know for each set in $\mathcal{F}(t)$ whether the true $\omega$ lies in that set'.

If $X(t)$ is the price at time $t$, so what are contained in $\mathcal{F}(t)$?
It is very helpful if there is an real example.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3131221/36150) (.. and the questions which you find "linked" there, on the right-hand side).

Comment: Thank you, I read your suggestion question before I asked my question, but I can't imagine how $\mathcal{F}(t)$ look like? I found some example bout $\mathcal{F}(t)$ with coin toss, it is easy to understand because it is discrete.

Comment: Well, but what do you expect? In general, a $\sigma$-algebra is huge (in the sense that it contains many sets). Unless you are in a very simple setting (e.g. coin toss) you cannot write down $\sigma(X)$ explicitly, even for a single random variable $X$, let alone a whole stochastic process.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I don't need the full value on $\mathcal{F}(t)$, just the type of data in $\mathcal{F}(t)$, set of $t$ or set of $X(t)$ or something else?